# DO File export Command

Tags: stata

I was wondering if there was a way in which I could export the data I create in Stata do file to the Stata file format of .dta.  I'm using the following code to create the dataset.

```
use data1, clear
foreach num of numlist 2/30 {
    append using data`num'
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `save alldata`?

Comment: Yeah that worked thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to specify a name and working directory as part of your Stata Do-File, `save "C:\Users\user\Desktop\name.dta"`should do the job.